# jQuery doesn' t work for AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have to resize the column width of my table that is located inside my directive. I found a valid framework to do that: 
[Resizable table columns with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156182/resizable-table-columns-with-jQuery). However, I have the following problem. Make the resize column works is quite simple, just add this jQuery code inside my Angular controller :

```
$("#normal").colResizable({
                liveDrag:true, 
                gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
                draggingClass:"dragging", 
                resizeMode:'fit'
            });
```

Where normal is the ID of my table, which is the following :

```
<table id="normal" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td>
            </tr>                                                                   
        </table>
```

Now the problem is that jQuery is not working for the table inside a directive, i mean , if i put the table inside a normal html page the resize of column width it works, but if i put the table code inside an AngularJs directive it doesn't work.

I have just the table inside my page, there is no other code that could influence the function of it.

I guess that the problem is the jQuery, but I'm not completely sure about it. I'm new to Angular and maybe there is something that I should do configure in my directive?

Comment: you mean that its not working with some custom directive?

Comment: @ NightsWatch Yes, exactly, i have just find the solution, i have to add the jquery code inside the directive instead of the controller.

Comment: Cool! I was thinking by giving replace : true property inside your custom directive might do the magic. If possible can you please try with this and share your feedback. It might help for someone else.

Comment: @NightsWatch Actually it already has the replace property set to true

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to utilize Angular only if you are not sure how DOM works and how to have a clean code of jquery within angular.

Try referring [Resizable columns with Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506512/resizable-columns-with-angularjs?answertab=active#tab-top)